# Convertir consulta SQL en una para Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Deseo convertir esta consulta `sql`:

```
   SELECT
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."id",
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."normal_retailer_delivery_id",
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."delivery_parameter_id",
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."event_start_date",
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."event_end_date",
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."enabled",
  "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."updated"
FROM "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"
WHERE ('2018-04-25' >= "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."event_start_date" AND
       '2018-04-25' <= "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."event_end_date" AND
       "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."enabled" = TRUE AND
       "misuper_calendareventsretailerdelivery"."normal_retailer_delivery_id" = 5)
```

En una de `Django ORM` descartando la posibilidad de utilizar `raw` lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
CalendarEventsRetailerDelivery.objects.filter(
enabled=True, normal_retailer_delivery=
normal_delivery_parameters, 
**{str(day_date) + '__gte': 'event_start_date',
str(day_date) + '__lte': 'event_end_date'})
```

Otra forma como lo he intentado es de la siguiente manera:

```
CalendarEventsRetailerDelivery.objects.extra(
                    where=[day_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " >= event_start_date AND " + day_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " <= event_end_date"]).get(
                    normal_retailer_delivery=normal_delivery_parameters, enabled=True)
```

Utilizando un `.extra` me da el siguiente erro:

```
LINE 1: ...alendareventsretailerdelivery" WHERE ((2018-04-18 >= event_s...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos.
```

Y tenido éxito, agradeciera su ayuda o pautas para poder solicitar esto.

Comment: Que errror te esta dando o que te esta fallando?

Comment: El error que me da es que '2018-04-25' que es el valor de mi variable, no es un field del modelo.  FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword '2018-04-18 12:00:00' into field. Choices are: delivery_parameter, delivery_parameter_id, enabled, event_end_date, event_start_date, id, normal_retailer_delivery, normal_retailer_delivery_id, updated

Answer (score 0):

pude dar solución a mi pregunta de la siguiente manera:

```
CalendarEventsRetailerDelivery.objects.extra(
                    where=[" %s >= event_start_date AND %s <= event_end_date"],
                    params=[day_date, day_date]).get(
                    normal_retailer_delivery=normal_delivery_parameters, enabled=True)
```

Si alguien tiene alguna mejor forma de hacerlo o una sugerencia estoy gustoso a recibir sus pautas.

Answer (score 0):

una idea idea como podrias hacerlo es con **filter**

**__level__lte**   menor o igual que

**__level__gte** mayor o igual que 
espero te sea de utilidad

```
CalendarEventsRetailerDelivery.objects.values().all().filter(event_start_date__level__gte='2018-04-25', event_end_date__level__lte='2018-04-25', etc..)
```